# What energy sources could exist beyond fusion?

Tags: science-based, physics, energy

I'm looking for possible sources of energy that could one day replace fusion.

I'm not necessarily looking for cool sounding names, as I'm trying to avoid technobabble, but ones that could somewhat be defended as possible replacements with a bit of real science.

Comment: In trying to answer the question myself, I have relied on looking for gradients to exploit or sources to arbitrage potential energy.

Comment: I do not believe this question provide any good criteria for determining which answer is best, which turns it into a List Question, simply looking for a bunch of alternatives to pick from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Matter - Antimatter Annihilation (Or just run matter into energy)

Have you heard about [mass-energy equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence)? It states that mass is equivalent to raw energy, and energy to mass in this formula:
$$E = mc^2$$
That means that each gram of matter has 89,875,517,873,681,764 Joules of energy, that is, 90 petajoules.

Annihilate a gram of matter with a gram of antimatter would release all that amount of energy. Fusion and fission already do this, but at lower efficiency (since not all mass is turned into energy).

## [Hawking Radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation)

From wikipedía:

> Hawking radiation reduces the mass and rotation energy of black holes and is therefore also known as black hole evaporation. Because of this, black holes that do not gain mass through other means are expected to shrink and ultimately vanish. Micro black holes are predicted to be larger emitters of radiation than larger black holes and should shrink and dissipate faster.
> [...]
> Hawking showed that quantum effects allow black holes to emit exact black-body radiation. The electromagnetic radiation is produced as if emitted by a black body with a temperature inversely proportional to the mass of the black hole.

Basically, as less mass a black hole as (and so smaller it is), more energy it produces.

I don't want to explain how that works, but in the title link you can see the explanation.

Using this [online calculator](http://xaonon.dyndns.org/hawking/) we know that a black hole of 1,000 kg would emit $3.56 \times 10^{26} W$, and last $8.4 \times 10^{(-8)} \text{ seconds}$. A black hole of 1,000,000 kg would emit $3.56 \times 10^{20} W$, but last $84 \text{ seconds}$.

Hawking radiation has a 100% [mass-energy equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence), more than fusion (less than 4%, citation needed).

## [Zero Point Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-point_energy)

From wikipedía:

> Physics currently lacks a full theoretical model for understanding zero-point energy; in particular the discrepancy between theorized and observed vacuum energy is a source of major contention. Physicists Richard Feynman and John Wheeler calculated the zero-point radiation of the vacuum to be an order of magnitude greater than nuclear energy, with a single light bulb containing enough energy to boil all the world's oceans. [...] Yet according to Einstein's theory of general relativity any such energy would gravitate and the experimental evidence from both the expansion of the universe, dark energy and the Casimir effect show any such energy to be exceptionally weak. [...] This discrepancy is known as the cosmological constant problem and it is one of the greatest unsolved mysteries in physics. Many physicists believe that "the vacuum holds the key to a full understanding of nature"

It's your story, so you could said that Zero Point Energy stores a massive amount of power, like [Stargate series did](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Zero_Point_Module).

## More

More information can be found in [this answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/118586/35041) I post last year:

- Quantum tunnelling and Heisenberg uncertainty principle.
- Dark energy generator.
- Vacuum energy (similar, if not the same as zero point energy).
- Virtual Particle Generator (Hawking radiation example).

Comment: It's accepted that the vacuum has some kind of energy (though see [here](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/vacuum.html) about ambiguities in how to measure it which may not be resolved until we have a theory of quantum gravity), but from what I've read physicists tend to scoff at the idea that this energy could be used as a power source even in principle, see [here](https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=1256) for an example. Hawking radiation from micro black holes is a physical possibility though, and you might also consider adding something about matter/antimatter annihilation.

Comment: As yes, exploiting the matter-antimatter asymmetry somehow. Thank you for your comment, and @ender for your answer

Comment: I'm not sure that Hawking Radiation can be used as a power _source_ as such... you need to create such lightweight black holes in the first place, and that process seems unlikely to be easy or let you get more energy _out_ than you put _in_. Not sure if anyone has even done any serious research into the engineering difficulties of creating singularities though...

Comment: @Starfish Prime - It would take energy to create one (perhaps by focusing powerful gamma lasers at a small point in space, i.e. a [Kugelblitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kugelblitz_%28astrophysics%29)), but once you have one you can dump matter in and get energy out indefinitely, potentially getting far more energy out then it took to create it. Yes, you are just converting the mass energy of the matter you dump in into radiation energy, but all forms of power generation are converting one form of energy (like the potential energy in nuclear bonds) into some more usable form like radiation.

Comment: @Hypnosifl dumping matter into it at speed is something of a challenge, though, given the size of the target you need to hit. Doing so efficiently seems likely to be a challenge. But I take your point.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that matter/antimatter is just one form of using E=MC^2. Both fission and fusion use it. Antimatter annihilating with matter is just a fair bit more dense and efficient. If we can find a way to generically turn matter into energy, then the available energy will be effectively infinite.

Comment: @sdfgeoff - True, though you can also say that fission/fusion are transforming the potential energy in nuclear bonds into kinetic energy (heat and radiation). According to E=mc^2 all forms of energy including potential contribute to the mass of a bound system, so potential energy in nuclear bonds does contribute to the rest mass of the nucleus (which is not just the sum of the rest masses of the protons and neutrons that make it up), but this is also true of ordinary chemical reactions that convert potential energy in atomic bonds into kinetic energy, which can also be understood with E=mc^2.

Comment: @Ender Look - Why do you say that zero-point energy is different from vacuum energy? It's true that zero-point energy is used in a more general way so it can refer to the lowest energy state of any system, not just the vacuum (for example the ground state of an electron in an atom has the zero point energy for that system), but in your discussion of zero-point energy you seemed to be talking specifically about drawing power from the vacuum, not some other type of system. The ZPE of the vacuum is synonymous with vacuum energy AFAIK. Also, I don't understand your comment about quantum tunneling.

Comment: @Hypnosifl, I wasn't exactly sure if there were or not the same thing, that is why I state "Vacuum energy (similar, if not the same as zero point energy).". What do you mean with quatum tunneling? The other answer I linked?

Comment: You mentioned quantum tunneling as a way of generating power in this answer and referred back to the other answer for more, but that answer doesn't talk about using it for power...is your idea that by controlling quantum tunneling one could reverse the 2nd law of thermodynamics and use the energy in systems previously at equilibrium/max entropy to do useful work? The 2nd law can be derived from basic quantum principles like unitarity as discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_thermodynamics#Emergence_of_the_second_law), so I think you'd need to modify the basic laws for this.

Comment: @Hypnosifl the answer I linked was about preventing the heat death of the universe. So it wasn't exactly about producing energy (it was more about reversing entropy), but with some modifications, it could be used for either... I think, I'm not exactly good at quantum physic.

Answer (score 5):

#### Non-orientable wormholes

The problem with antimatter is that you have to expend energy to create it. It might serve as a good energy storage medium, and there are interesting things you can do with animatter that you can't trivially do by other means, but by itself it isn't a *source* of energy and it couldn't replace fusion (there are potentially similar problems with creating small black holes that produce useful amounts of hawking radiation, but those might perhaps be worked around).

However, imagine if you had a means to construct a [non-orientable wormhole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-orientable_wormhole). Things you feed through a non-orientable wormhole may come out the other side, but their [chirality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(physics)) (or "handedness") will be flipped. Dextro-amino-acids become their levo-equivalents. Southpaws come out as regular boxers. **Matter comes out as antimatter**.

Suddenly every fleck of matter in the universe is a source of a great deal more energy than you could ever get out of it from fusion alone.

---

#### Strangelets

If you don't believe in wormholes and like your power sources to be more dangerous than black holes, consider [strangelets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strangelet). It is possible that massive strangelets are more stable than their smaller versions, and in that case it may be practical to throw a lump of regular matter into a strangelet which will convert it to strange matter and release a generous quantity of gamma rays. You obviously wouldn't want one of these anywhere near your star or planet, and it doesn't give you as much energy as actually annihilating the inflowing matter would, but it would be a pretty effective power source nonetheless.

---

#### Q-balls

If you'd prefer something a little safer, you might like [Q-balls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-ball). No spacetime-warping trickery required, but you may need to live in a universe with supersymmetry and it increasingly looks like we don't. That aside, these are exotic forms of quark matter, related to strangelets. Unlike strangelets, q-balls don't eat up everything and emit gamma rays, and perhaps more importantly from a safety point of view can be charged and so trapped in a suitable electromagnetic apparatus. If you take the right kind of q-ball, and shoot a beam of the right kind of particle at it, [the particles will be reflected off with their chirality changed](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0405044.pdf): another source of antimatter.

It is remotely possible that [natural q-balls exist](https://arxiv.org/PS_cache/astro-ph/pdf/0508/0508391v2.pdf) and might be harvested, if any were found within practical range of your spacecraft.

Comment: WOW! You went two steps beyond fusion!!! Very fascinating stuff. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

**Penrose process**

By splitting a chunk of matter in two near a black hole in such a way that one piece drops into the black hole and the other escapes it, one can extract its rotational energy.

This has way better energy efficiency than fusion (about 29% of original BH mass can be harvested), possibly more when using charged black holes.

[Description on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_process)